# Is there some way to specify keywords for windows search for my application?

Tags: windows, windows-search

I am maintaining an application. My company want that application to be easily findable by our customers. I am looking for a way where our customers can find the application by typing related keywords in the windows search box.

Currently you can find the application by typing parts of its name. But I want our customers to also find it when they type some related word that is not directly in the name.

For example, when I type "spreadsheet", then excel pops up.

[image]

Can I also define some related words, or is there some other way I can provide additional words the search box looks for?

Answer (score -2):

If this software is mandatory for all users in your company you should see with your IT Department to pin it by default on all computers in your company. (GPO or MDM)

Comment: I am looking for a solution for our customers. That they just have to install, and it should be easily findable. Preferable when they search for our company name or related brand name. I can't put all that in the shortcut name.

Comment: then you have to search on the indexation parameters defined on the computer. The location where you application is located must be part of the indexation list.